# How to avoid big floats appearing at the end of the document?

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

I'm writing a document which contains a lot of big figures and tables. Usually I use `[htb]` for the float position, however, when the float occupies an entire page, it's placed in the next page, O.K!, but when I continue writing, the float jumps to the last page, E. G.:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Example table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
\toprule
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why the table is placed in the last page intead of the second page and continues the text in the last page? how can I avoid this?

Comment: A simple tabular cannot split between pages.

Comment: @Johannes_B I understood the question as in "why is the tabular not on page 2"

Comment: @samcarter Also my first thought, but i cannot test the example with the phone :-)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

If you allow the table to be placed on its own page by adding `p` to the floating arguments, the table will not be pushed to the end.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Example table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
\toprule
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]